# defining a lambda and capturing this leads to confusing compiler error

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm getting a compiler error when trying to define a lambda capturing `this` in the constructor of an object. It looks like this:

```
typedef int (*HANDLER)(char*, int);
struct Foo {
bool member;
Foo() {
     HANDLER h1 = [](char* one, int two)->int {
         return 0;         // fine
     };
     HANDLER h2 = [](char* one, int two)->int {
         member = false;   // error: 'this' was not captured - understood
         return 0;
      };
     HANDLER h3 = [this](char* one, int two)->int {
         member = false;   // ok now but other error as below
         return 0;
      };
   }
};
```

`h1` is trivial and compiles fine. `h2` doesn't compile, because the member variable `member` is not captured. This also makes sense. But when I add `this` to the capture to get access to `member`, I get an error message that I'm struggling to parse:

```
mcve.cpp: In constructor ‘Foo::Foo()’:
mcve.cpp:16:11: error: cannot convert ‘Foo::Foo()::<lambda(char*, int)>’ to ‘HANDLER {aka int (*)(char*, int)}’ in initialization
       };
       ^
```

This is using gcc 4.9.1 with -std=c++14, though I get the same error with clang-1000.11.45.5 on a Mac. Note that the `HANDLER` function pointer typedef is something I'm working with from an external library.

Comment: a lambda with a capture is fundamentally different from a free function, try `std::function` which works basically with any callable

Comment: if you are not allowed to change `HANDLER` you are out of luck

Comment: A capture-less lambda has no data it needs to store and so is safely convertible to a function pointer, but a lambda with a capture needs to store the captured data somewhere, and so can't be represented by just a function pointer. Use `std::function<int(char*,int)>`.

Comment: HANDLER is from someone else's code, I can't change it. Should I be able to use `std::bind` here, or will I run into the same problem?